# Meteor call template method from another method

Tags: javascript, jquery, methods, callback, meteor

I want to call a method within a method for clientside but I don't know how to handle it, i've tried by calling like `myFunction()`and `this.myFunction()` but it is not working... This is my code

```
Template.decision.rendered = function () {
    if ($(".active").length == 0) {
        var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000);
        var $items = $(".item");
        $items.eq(random % $items.length).addClass("active");
    }
    $.each($(".item"), function (index, value) {
        if (Session.get($(this).attr('id'))) {
            this.showResults(value.option);
        }
    });
};
Template.decision.showResults = function($option) {
    $('#result').html('Option ' + $option + ' is voted');
};
```

As you can see I want to call `showResults` for each item inside `rendered` callback...

Answer (score 1):

Found it using `Template.decision.showResults();` silly me.

Answer (score 1):

I think that a better way depending on what you are trying to do would be either to use a Session variable or a Meteor Method:

#### Session Variable.

```
Template.decision.created = function() {
  Session.setDefault('showResults', false);
}

Template.decision.rendered = function() {
  // [...]

  $.each($(".item"), function (index, value) {
    if (Session.get($(this).attr('id'))) {
      Session.set('showResults', true);
    }
  });
}

Template.decision.showResults = function() {
   return Session.get('showResults');
}

// in your template
<template name="decision">
  {{#if showResults}}
    <p>Here is the results.</p>
  {{/if}}
</template>
```

#### Meteor Method.

```
// On the client.
Template.decision.rendered = function() {
  // [...]

  $.each($(".item"), function (index, value) {
    if (Session.get($(this).attr('id'))) {
      Meteor.call('showResults', function(error, result) {
        if (!error and result === true) {
          $('.class').hide()  // It is here that you modify the DOM element according to the server response and your needs.
        }
      });
    }
  });
}

// Server-side method
// But, if you want it to react like a stub, put it inside your lib folder.
Meteor.methods({
  showResults: function() {
    // do your thing
    result = true; // let's say everything works as expected on server-side, we return true
    return result;
  }
});
```

Comment: But what if I want to edit DOM elements inside showResults method? It won't work inside Meteor.methods, right? Let's say for example instead `Console.log("Voted");` I want to do `$('#voted').html('Voted');`

Comment: You cannot edit DOM elements inside Meteor.methods (as you are server-side and jQuery is only available on the client) but this will work in the Meteor.call callback (as the code is run client-side).

Comment: Can you show me an example of Meteor.call callback to manipulate DOM elements? Because it is the final purpose, I will update my question with an example..

Comment: Basically is what I asked, how to call methods to manipulate DOM elements, I don't want any complex stuff, just manipulate a DOM from a method.